# Characters are appended while reading from a file and sending data to server

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am reading data from a file and sending this to server using windows sockets. Following is the code:

```
//Socket creation and setup code

long Begin;
long End;
char * block;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(filepath, ios::in | ios::binary);
Begin = myfile.tellg();
myfile.seekg(0,ios::end);
End = myfile.tellg();
unsigned long size = End - Begin;
int Div = (int)size / 1024;
int Mod = (int)size % 1024;
int len = strlen(name);
send(theSocket,(const char*)&len,sizeof(int),0);
send(theSocket,name,strlen(name),0);
send(theSocket, (const char*)&size, sizeof(unsigned long), 0);
block = new char[1024];
for (int i=0; i<Div; i++)
{
    myfile.seekg(i*1024);
    myfile.read(block,1024);
    cout << block << endl;
    send(theSocket,block,1024,0);
}
if (Mod != 0)
{
    block = new char[Mod];
    myfile.seekg(Div*1024);
    myfile.read(block,Mod+1);
    send(theSocket,block,Mod,0);
}
delete [] block;
myfile.close();
closesocket(theSocket);
WSACleanup();
```

The problem I am having is when I read data from a file into `block`, it appends few weird characters at the end. The characters are the same every time like this=> **"ýýýý««««««««îþîþ"**. Can't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason you're seeing some garbage characters is due to the following:

```
block = new char[1024];
...
myfile.seekg(i*1024);
myfile.read(block,1024);
cout << block << endl;
```

You are reading 1024 characters into a `char` array, and then passing that to `std::cout`.  When you pass a `char*` (which is how a char array is referenced) to `std::cout`, it is expecting it to be zero-terminated.  For this to work, you would need your `block` array to be of size 1025, and ensure that the last byte is zero (`block[1024] = 0;`).  Without this zero-termination, the output will be random memory values from directly after the array.

Note also that if you read in a zero as part of the data, then this will also be considered as terminating the string when outputting to `cout`.